# Solve $\int_{0}^{\infty} a^{ix^2}$ dx with contour integration?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty} a^{ix^2} dx$$ for $0<a<1$ using contour integration methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a^{ix^2}=\left(e^{\ln a}\right)^{ix^2}$$
so you have:
$$I=\int_0^\infty e^{i\ln(a)x^2}dx$$
then I'd suggest using the substitution $u=\sqrt{\ln(a)}x$

Comment: I should have noticed the identity with the exponential and the natural log. Thanks for the help!